# Command to get Hard disk & processor spec remotely

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

What is the command(s) helps to get information of the Hard disk & processor in a remote windows machine ?

Comment: Via command line? Programmatically? What language?

Comment: yes command line as already tagged.

Comment: Use the following command with '/node':

wmic /node:<server> /output:<filespec> /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_diskdrive get /all /format:csv

Where <server> is an IP or DNS of the remote system. You'll need admin access to obtain details else may need to use something else like psexec.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you can rely on running on Windows Vista or later, then you can use WMIC. For details on WMIC, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx.

To get CPU information try `wmic cpu`

To get hard disk information try either `wmic diskdrive` or `wmic logicaldisk` depending on whether you want information of the disk devices or logical drives.

Since the lines will often wrap, making it difficult to read in a console window, try this variant to redirect the output to text files:

```
wmic cpu > cpu.txt
wmic diskdrive > diskdrive.txt
wmic logicaldisk > logicaldisk.txt
```

You can then examine the files `cpu.txt`, `diskdrive.txt` and `logicaldisk.txt` at your convenience.

Comment: This is strange: free hex editor on the Internet (HxD) that has possibility to open physical drive sees 256060514288 bytes of size on my SSD, while wmic diskdrive sees less - 256052966400 bytes. That is wmic sees 7547888 bytes less. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: These commands are working good for local machine but how do you fire them for a remote machine? I believe the OP was interested in a remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command: msinfo32

and then press Ctrl+R to put the computer IP that you want to connect

Answer (score 1):

I would use "systeminfo", that's what I would use to find most things about my computer